# Cakephp not redirecting after sending email through CakeEmail

Tags: php, email, cakephp, redirect

In CakePHP 2.X, for one of my controller actions, I am trying to send an email to all user's every time a new record is created.

Updated with drmonkeyninja's suggestions:

```
// NewslettersContoller.php

public function add() {
  if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Newsletter->create();

  if($this->Newsletter->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your newsletter has been submited.'));
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Newsletter->id));
  }
  else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
  }
 }
}

// Newsletter.php
public function afterSave($created, $options = []) {
  parent::afterSave($created, $options);
  if ($created === true) {
    $newsletter = $this->findById($this->id);

    // Get all users with an email address.
    $emails = ClassRegistry::init('User')->find(
        'list',
        array(
            'fields' => array(
                'User.id',
                'User.email'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.email <>' => null
            )
        )
    );

    $Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
    $Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'Caprock Portal'));
    $Email->to($emails);
    $Email->subject($newsletter['Newsletter']['title']);
    $Email->message($newsletter['Newsletter']['content']);
    try {
       $Email->send();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->log($exception);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code snippet, I use CakeEmail to send every user an email containing the newsletter created in the action. Unfortunately for some reason, every time CakeEmail finishes sending the email, CakePHP ignores my redirect request and proceeds to render a blank view (route is still add). I have verified that it is the CakeEmail function by commenting it and verifying that redirection starts to work again. Nothing is caught in the try-catch block either.

One of my assumptions for the cause of this problem is that the email headers are interfering with the redirect headers for my action. I inspected the network requests through my browser, but nothing seems to be sent out, except from the original post request to the add function.

Comment: remove `return` and check.

Comment: Please check and tell what happen?

Comment: nop, nothing. Keeps rendering a blank view

Comment: on your debug mode and check error. `config.php make debug mode to 2`.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh debug mode is already set to 2

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to send the email from the Newsletter model in the `afterSave()` callback:-

```
// app/Model/Newsletter.php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

public function afterSave($created, $options = []) {
    parent::afterSave($created, $options);
    if ($created === true) {
        $newsletter = $this->findById($this->id);

        // Get all users with an email address.
        $emails = ClassRegistry::init('User')->find(
            'list',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'User.id',
                    'User.email'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.email <>' => null
                )
            )
        );

        $Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
        $Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'Caprock Portal'));
        $Email->to($emails);
        $Email->subject($newsletter['Newsletter']['title']);
        $Email->message($newsletter['Newsletter']['content']);
        try {
           $Email->send();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->log($exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Your controller action would then just be:-

```
// app/Controller/NewslettersController.php
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Newsletter->create();
        if ($this->Newsletter->save($this->request->data)) {
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Newsletter->id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        }
    }
}
```

If the view is still not rendering then temporarily disable the `afterSave()` callback to check that the Controller part of the code is working as expected when saving your newsletter.

Note that you can filter out the users without an email address when you retrieve the users from the database. By using `find('list')` you don't need to mess with a `foreach` loop.

You also don't need to use `$this->Newsletter->getLastInsertId();` as `$this->Newsletter->id` should have already been set to this at the time of save.

Cake's `debug()` method is better to use when debugging variables than `var_dump()` which incidentally won't work in your example as your are redirecting after it has been output!

Comment: this seems like a good alternative. I will try it out and report back if it works. By the way, thanks for the debug() function tip, I had no idea. Although, the var_dump does work how I have it setup since my function does not redirect. The blank page that is rendered displays the var_dump, which in this case is the email's headers.

Comment: I just tried it, and it still stops the redirect. I disabled the callback to verify that it wasn't a controller issue. The controller works without the callback, and stops working as soon as I enable it again.

Comment: Have you remembered to include the CakeEmail library using `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');`? I've just updated my example code to show this in the model.

Comment: yeah, its in there. The emails are being sent out, the only problem is the controller.

Comment: I just updated the answer to try and catch issues with the sending of the email, but looks like this isn't the problem for you. Might be worth a try anyway :-(

Comment: It caught an error, but apparently its a syntax error.  I'll update the main post to include it. thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: Nevermind, I misspelled something. The try-catch didn't catch anything regarding the redirect :/

Comment: Have you checked the server logs for PHP errors that don't get logged by CakePHP? I suspect you have an issue with your headers, but don't see why from the code example. I regularly send emails in this fashion.

Comment: I checked the logs, but there is nothing. Although  I just found something really peculiar. When I try to redirect using the header function( instead of CakePHP's helpers ), the view is actually rendered, rather than the blank page I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try specifying the controller in the url array:

```
if($Email->send()) {
    return $this->redirect(
            array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'view', $id)
        );
} else  {
    return $this->redirect(
            array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'add')
        );
}
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but it CakePHP still doesn't redirect.

Comment: Navigate `app/tmp/logs/error.log ` See the what  is gives the system error

Comment: Just checked the logs, nothing. I can see other errors, but nothing is logged when the emails are sent.

Comment: on your debug mode in `app/config/core.php` like  `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Comment: once use `$this->redirect('/controller/view/<id>');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var_dump`. It breaks HTTP protocol if you try to send header information (for the redirect) *after* content has already been sent.

Comment: I forgot to remove the var_dump before posting the question. The problem persists with and without the var_dump. I just put as a means to check the headers the send function was creating.

Comment: Do you get *any* output when the redirect fails?

Comment: when I use the var_dump, I can see the headers for the send function. The view is completely blank if I remove the var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to send the emails out as a Shell/Console using a Cronjob.

This is a link to the book where you can find a bunch of information about creating shells.

CakePHP 3.x
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html

CakePHP 2.x
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

This eliminates blocking your processing. If you send emails in controller or model, your app is still waiting for the emails to be sent before the page is rendered or redirected. So by moving to a cronjob the user has as faster better experience because the are not waiting for emails to be sent out.

So how do you know what to send out via the shell??? Well that depends on your use case but I flag records that need sent with a database column for this purpose, find all the ones that haven't been sent, mark those found records with another flag as being processed, the second flag in the database prevents two cron tasks from reading and sending the same records while the first cronjob is still processing. I like to set my cronjobs for mailing as low as possible for transaction type emails, however that can depend on the hosting provider and their settings.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, although doesn't get to the bottom of the problem with the app being described. I personally use the Queue plugin (https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue/tree/2.x) to remove the need to send emails inline with the code. This is a very flexible approach to avoid code blocking critical processes.

Comment: Cool, I will check that plugin out, thanks for sharing. I think removing the email from controller and/or model and using shells or the cakephp-queue plugin makes more sense, because otherwise the redirect or render is not going to happen until the messages are sent. If there are SMTP errors or timeout issue, then panicking user start refreshing, which could add to the problem and flood people with unwanted emails. I sometimes implement a column to store the number of failed attempts sending a message. This is handy if the SMTP server is down you know later on your cronjob will try again.